# graphql - how to make modify the structure of the returned data

Tags: javascript, typescript, graphql, gatsby, strapi

**Background**
My site is created using **Gatsby**, alongside with **strapi**(which provides graphql query), and **apollo client** for fetching the data.

**Current Implementation**

I just start integrating strapi in my application.

getArticles.ts

```
import { gql } from "@apollo/client";

export const GET_ARTICLES = gql`
  query Article {
    articles {
      data {
        id
        attributes {
          title
          description
          date
        }
      }
    }
  }
`;
```

which I use in

```
const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(GET_ARTICLES);
```

when I log `data`, it looks like

```
{
  "data": {
    "articles": {
      "data": [
        {
          "id": "1",
          "attributes": {
            "title": "Article 1",
            "description": "This is the first article",
            "date": "2023-06-23"
          }
        },
        {
          "id": "2",
          "attributes": {
            "title": "Article 2",
            "description": "This is the second article",
            "date": "2023-06-24"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

**Expected Behaviour**

What I want for `data` is actually

```
[
        {
          "id": "1",
          "attributes": {
            "title": "Article 1",
            "description": "This is the first article",
            "date": "2023-06-23"
          }
        },
        {
          "id": "2",
          "attributes": {
            "title": "Article 2",
            "description": "This is the second article",
            "date": "2023-06-24"
          }
        }
]
```

I don't know which layer(s) I should modify in order to achieve above result. Can anyone provide suggestions for that?

gatsby-configs.ts

```
    {
      resolve: "gatsby-source-strapi",
      options: {
        apiURL: process.env.STRAPI_API_URL || "http://127.0.0.1:1337",
        accessToken: process.env.STRAPI_TOKEN,
        collectionTypes: [
          {
            singularName: "article",
            queryParams: {
"preview" : "live",
              populate: {
                cover: "*",
                blocks: {
                  populate: "*",
                },
              },
            },
          }
        ]
      },
    },
```

**Update 1**

Replying to the comment, yes I can add one extra code like
`const myData = data?.articles.?data` in my component file.

However that's mean I have to add this line of code after every graphql query. That's why I want to know, by any chance, I can just retrieve the data I want, like what I show in the post

Comment: Those look pretty much the same; what are you hoping to change?

Answer (score 0):

You're not going to get exactly what you want because the upper level `data` object has to exist. Your best bet would be to modify your schema so that this query:

```
import { gql } from "@apollo/client";

export const GET_ARTICLES = gql`
  query Article {
    articles {
      data {
        id
        attributes {
          title
          description
          date
        }
      }
    }
  }
`
```

becomes this query:

```
import { gql } from "@apollo/client";

export const GET_ARTICLES = gql`
  query Article {
    articles {
      id
      attributes {
        title
        description
        date
      }
    }
  }
`
```

So then your `articles` will be returning an array of type `article` so it looks like this:

```json
{
  "data": {
    "articles": [
      {
        "id": "1",
        "attributes": {
          "title": "Article 1",
          "description": "This is the first article",
          "date": "2023-06-23"
        }
      },
      {
        "id": "2",
        "attributes": {
          "title": "Article 2",
          "description": "This is the second article",
          "date": "2023-06-24"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

To get the data in the format you're looking for you can then do something like this:

```
const articles = data.articles
```

which will provide the array you're looking for. If Strapi is providing the query and schema then you may have to review their documentation to see if this is possible. Otherwise you'll need to do something like `const articles = data.articles?.data` to get the array of articles.